# Should users be given the option to sign up to a website without having to set a password?

Tags: password

For many sites as a user I'm not really bothered about security as there's little of value on the site

So should users be given the **option** of signing up to a website without setting a password ?

Comment: I can agree with you sometimes it really doesn't feel necessary. For example in a previous building I lived in we booked laundry time using a web portal. There you had to sign in using a serial number and a password. Not one time did I feel that I appreciated the level of security. In a commercial or social context there could be a difference though. I guess you have to weigh in how much potential damage someone unauthorized could pose using the service, and from there determine whether disabling authentication is an option. In a laundry context, I'd say the potential damage is slim to none.

Comment: @PhillipW can you give an example of a site (or type of site) where you'd want to sign up without a password?

Comment: I guess its any site where I think: " would I really care if someone else accessed 'my account' ".  ie particularly when I intend to use a site just once.  I'll watch for examples as they come up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say often we already can.

An example I can think of is guest checkout, where you still provide the site with details and complete a transaction. You can even have reward points collected for you and get other account type stuff and you can be encouraged to sign up later. Often with online purchases we just want to buy, probably from a recognisable brand and see the site process our details in a secure way, then leave, never go back and not care about having an account.

Well designed sites don't push registration into the face of the user, for example, [as noted here in a beautiful but extreme example](http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button/), forcing registration during checkout and not just letting people checkout. This is the best example of what you describe actually already happening a lot.

Or another example would be newsletter signup or blog subscription. You are signing up for notifications from a site without actually using a password.

In these cases you aren't quite anonymous in the same way as a cursory visitor.

As soon as you have any sort of site specific area where you might want to interact with other users, store sensitive data or in some way behave in a way that can be connected with an IP / email address then there needs to be a protective wall created and you move from being anonymous to signed up.

Answer (score 1):

This is different to a guest checkout in that you are expecting the user to presumably come back and sign in again.  Curious - why are you so anxious to get them to sign up?  Is this for CRM or cross device data tracking purposes?  I think you might be best off hitting the middle road and asking folks to choose a picture and a number so it's not completely unwalled.  If you are collecting PII you will want to enforce a password btw so the user feels validated their info is safe